# How are biases adjusted in neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, bias-neuron

I'm learning about neural networks.
I saw many videos, PDFs etc telling about adjusting the weights in backpropagation. But nowhere i saw someone explaining how adjusting the biases work.

Can anyone here give me a brief explanation on how the biases are adjusted?

Comment: exactly the same way. Bias is just another weight. You can think of it as a weight multiplied by a constant extra "1" input/feature.

Comment: ^^^ yup, think of biases as another input only the input is always 1.

Comment: @lejlot, But weights are multiplied and biases are added, how can they be adjusted together without meddling with other

Comment: That's not true. They look different, but are the same. Look at a linear layer. `f(x) = <w, x> + b = SUM_{i=1} w_i x_i + b = SUM_{i=0} w_i x_i,` where `x_0 := 1, w_0 := b`